# How do you find and change a value inside a javascript call using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

How do I find and CHANGE a value in the javascript call below using JQuery. Specifically, the following values: , 1, 1, 0, 0, 'No'. Then change the to say: , 2, 2, 0, 0, 'Yes'.

Code

`<div class="ArrowDiv"><a href="javascript:ValidateFormFieldValue('form1','TelligentUpdate.asp', 1, 1, 0, 0, 'No', 'ORDER^BY^WebSiteDocumentAlias.ixtCode^asc', 0, 'Next','','Update', '','','','','','','', '', '', '', '', '');" onclick="doSubmitButton();doSubmit();"  onmouseover="window.status='';return true;" onmouseout="window.status='';return true;"><img src="/telligent/images/StyleBlueRocket/ArrowRight.jpg" width="19" height="19" border="0" title="Next" align="absMiddle"></a></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most strait forward way would be to:

```
$('.ArrowDiv>a')[0].attr("href", "javascript:ValidateFormFieldValue('form1','TelligentUpdate.asp', 2, 2, 0, 0, 'Yes', 'ORDER^BY^WebSiteDocumentAlias.ixtCode^asc', 0, 'Next','','Update', '','','','','','','', '', '', '', '', '');");
```

But that is unreadable

```
var values = [
    "'form1','TelligentUpdate.asp', 1, 1, 0, 0, 'No', 'ORDER^BY^WebSiteDocumentAlias.ixtCode^asc', 0, 'Next','','Update', '','','','','','','', '', '', '', '', ''",
    "'form1','TelligentUpdate.asp', 2, 2, 0, 0, 'Yes', 'ORDER^BY^WebSiteDocumentAlias.ixtCode^asc', 0, 'Next','','Update', '','','','','','','', '', '', '', '', ''"
];

//wrap the following in an event
var myDiv = $('.ArrowDiv>a')[0];
var functionName = 'ValidateFormFieldValue';
var myDivValue = myDiv.attr('href').split('javascript:'+functionName+'(')[1].slice(0, - 1);
if (values.indexOf(myDivValue)===1){
    myDiv.attr('href', 'javascript:'+functionName+'('+values[0]+')');
} else if (values.indexOf(myDivValue)===0) {
    myDiv.attr('href', 'javascript:'+functionName+'('+values[1]+')');
};
```

That should work, if it doesn't, check the myDivValue variable. You might also want to modify the code to make it more efficient. An example is to make the strings in the `values` arrays to make it easier to modify.